# How can I remove all html tags from an array?

Tags: php, html, arrays, regex, string

Is there a function in php to do a regex replace kind of action on all entries of an array?
I have an array that contains lots of html tags with text in them and I want to remove the tags.
So basically I'm converting this:

```
$m = [
"<div>first string </div>",
"<table>
   <tr>
     <td style='color:red'>
       second string
     </td>
   </tr>
 </table>",
"<a href='/'>
   <B>third string</B><br/>
 </a>",
];
```

to this:

```
$m = [
"first string",
"second string",
"third string"
]
```

The regex that (hopefully) matches everything I want to remove, looks like this:

```
/<.+>/sU
```

The question is just how I should use it now? (My array actually has more than 50 entries and in every entry there can be like 10 matches, so using preg_replace is probably not the way to go, or is it?)

Comment: Simple way is to strip the tags, i'm not sure about regex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No need for a regex here, just use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to get rid of all html tags and then simply `trim()` the output, e.g.

```
$newArray = array_map(function($v){
    return trim(strip_tags($v));
}, $m);
```

Comment: To add to JessGabriel's answer:

Starting in PHP 8.1, you can't pass NULLs to internal function parameters (https://php.watch/versions/8.1/internal-func-non-nullable-null-deprecation). So for strip_tags, I have a quick and dirty if statement (if (is_null($v)) so it doesn't toss an error.

Comment: This is a wonderful solution, simple and quite fast. Be aware that the array passed needs to be a single dimensional array for this to work. @TechJunkie thanks for the hint about checking for `null` values.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do the following if you want regex approach:

```
$array = preg_replace("/<.+>/sU", "", $array);
```

Answer (score 3):

[array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

```
$m = array_map( 'strip_tags', $m );
```

The same principle goes for trimming.

Answer (score 1):

Here a variant for multidimensional arrays with object checking

```
/**
     * @param array $input
     * @param bool $easy einfache Konvertierung für 1-Dimensionale Arrays ohne Objecte
     * @param boolean $throwByFoundObject
     * @return array
     * @throws Exception
     */
    static public function stripTagsInArrayElements(array $input, $easy = false, $throwByFoundObject = true)
    {
        if ($easy) {
            $output = array_map(function($v){
                return trim(strip_tags($v));
            }, $input);
        } else {
            $output = $input;
            foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
                if (is_string($value)) {
                    $output[$key] = trim(strip_tags($value));
                } elseif (is_array($value)) {
                    $output[$key] = self::stripTagsInArrayElements($value);
                } elseif (is_object($value) && $throwByFoundObject) {
                    throw new Exception('Object found in Array by key ' . $key);
                }
            }
        }
        return $output;
    }
```

Comment: many objects have ->toString() method or can be (string)$casted.

Answer (score 0):

For associative multidimensional arrays, I prefer to use `array_walk_recursive`:

```
array_walk_recursive(
    $array, 
    function(&$string) {
        if (is_string($string)) {
            $string = trim(strip_tags($string));
        }
    }
);
```

See documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

If you are sure in your data, then `is_string` can be skipped like:

```
array_walk_recursive($stepViewEntity, 'strip_tags');
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved on a single line with `array_map()` and `strip_tags()`

```
$newArray = array_map(fn ($value): string => strip_tags($value), $oldArray);
```