# Search in Multidimensional Array with PHP after array_walk - didnt find string

Tags: php, html, arrays, search

this is giving me a headache: I have some array, which is some html code like this:

```
array_walk($data, function(&$value, $key) {
    $value['post_content'] = htmlentities($value['post_content']);
});
var_dump ($data);
```

the array dump is like that, I have taken some key out of the big array, its a website:

```
[20]=> array(1) { ["post_content"]=> string(20645) "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"> <html><body> <font rwr="1" size="2" style="font-family:Arial">"}
```

now I would like to go thorugh that array and find some stings and replace them with nothing to delete theme.
I am trying

```
$html = array_values($data);
if (array_search("font", $html)) {
    echo "Ist DRIN";
}       else      { echo "NEIN"; }
```

also I have tryed to search after fliped the array, and so on, but never find something to work with. 
Where is my error? thanks

Comment: array_map is what you're looking for with the 1st parameter being the function

Comment: `function searching($s)
{
if (array_search("Lenovo", $html)) {
    echo "Ist DRIN";
}       else      { echo "NEIN"; }
return $s;
}
print_r(array_map("searching",$data)); `  I wrote this function and use array_map, but still output is no, but there are strings like Lenovo in array

Comment: So when I use only 1 key with this code; i can get a result, but not with the whole array: `$ergebnis = $data[20]['post_content'];
var_dump ($ergebnis);
if (strpos($ergebnis, 'DOCTYPE')) {
    echo "Ist DRIN";
}       else      { echo "NEIN"; }

echo strpos($ergebnis, 'DOCTYPE');`

Comment: It looks like it is an array of arrays, the [20] suggests that the overarching array has more than 20 entries, and each entry is an array in itself, that has keys including post_content. So you have to split up your logic to account for that

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a good way to deal with it. It was quite straightforward but we tend to think complicated when problems seems big ;)

```
for($i=0; $i < 1000; $i++)
    {
        echo strpos($data[$i]['post_content'], $searchstring)."<br />";
    }
```

I just go through the keys with a for function and insert it into the first index place of my array.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
$newArray = array_map(function($v){
  return trim(strip_tags($v)); 
}, $m);
```

might be it can help you,
Your question has answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614584/how-can-i-remove-all-html-tags-from-an-array)